# Using Timestamps to Remove Expired Objects from multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript

I am hoping someone can help me with something that seems rather straightforward.

I have a Javascript Array that is multidimentional. Each object in the parent array contains two elements, the first of which is a timestamp:

```
[
  [1528438887, {
    "animal": "cat"
  }],
  [1528438898, {
    "animal": "dog"
  }],
  [1528438914, {
    "animal": "horse"
  }],
  [1528438927, {
    "animal": "seal"
  }]
]
```

I would simply like to remove all elements from this multidimensional array where the timestamp (i.e. element[0] of each object) is greater than 60 seconds old.

Any ideas on how to approach this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the limit given the current timestamp, and then use `filter`:

```js
const arr = [
  [1528438887, {
    "animal": "cat"
  }],
  [1528438898, {
    "animal": "dog"
  }],
  [1528438914, {
    "animal": "horse"
  }],
  [1528438927, {
    "animal": "seal"
  }],
  [1548438927, {
    "animal": "passing"
  }],
];
const limit = (Date.now() / 1000) - 60;
console.log(
  arr.filter(([timestamp]) => timestamp > limit)
);
```